# How can you create two equaly wide elements, relative to the largest of the two, while keeping a flexible 'structure' using only html/css?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to achieve the following using only html and css but I can't seem to get it right.
Consider the following image:
[image]

The image shows two desired outputs depending on their pseudo media queries min-width: X and max-width: X. It doesn't really matter what the media queries are, what is important is that the structure is able change so the output matches that of the image.

So what I've been struggling with is to have single-lined texts in the grey containers marked 'a' and have these containers have the same width relative to the largest of the two. The width of 'a' accomidate texts of variable lengths, not more not less. I also want 'a' to be lined out to the left as much as possible.

Remember I'm trying to accomplish this using only HTML and CSS.

Comment: CSS Tables, Flexbox and CSS Grid could probably do that but without your code and knowing what you have tried it's hard to be specific.

Comment: @Paulie_D I wasn't looking for any specific way to do it, I just wanted it to and any past attempts using table or flexbox failed. Besides I didn't want to limit the answer to any predefined structure or technique so I omitted my code deliberately. Perhaps this was an error of judgement on my part? Anyway I'd came up with a solution using a table as posted below. I would very much welcome you to add any other possible solution to this problem using other techniques (or whatever you would call them) like flexbox and css grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving my problem with using a table. The key lay in changing the display property of the td elements.

```css
table {
  width:300px;
  background-color:#4192AD;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}

td {
  height:20px;
}

td:first-child{
    width:1%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:right;    
    background-color:#C6C6C6;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:#73AD5A;
}

.alternate td {
  display:block;
  width:auto;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>short-text</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>relatively-long-text</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class='alternate'>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>short-text</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>relatively-long-text</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```